# MVN Dependency Mediation Fail - Resolving to multiple versions of the same dependency

Tags: spring, maven, dependency-management, mvn-repo

As per the dependency mediation rules mentioned [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), jackson-datatype-jsr310 at all places should resolve to one version.

But I see multiple versions below in this format. (version managed from {{version}}; omitted for duplicate)

Can someone explain this behavior?

```
[INFO] Building def web 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:3.6.28 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ def-web ---
[INFO] artifact arcesium.enterprise:enterprise-commons: checking for updates from central
[INFO] abc.def.web:def-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.2:compile - version managed from 2.9.8; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- abc.def.hr:def-hr:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.arcesium.mca:ccas:jar:20220611.RC2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.arcesium.radar:radar-client:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.arcesium.commons:http-utils:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.2:compile - version managed from 2.13.3; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        \- com.arcesium.radar:radar-model:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |           \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.2:compile - version managed from 2.8.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- abc.def.mdpayment:mdpayment:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.arcesium.frames:frames-client-core:jar:10.5.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |     \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.2:compile - version managed from 2.13.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- abc.def.commons:def-commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] \- abc:auth:jar:2.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- abc.moss:moss-framework-client:jar:20161119:compile
[INFO]       \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.2:compile - version managed from 2.6.1; omitted for duplicate)
```

Comment: What version do you see in `mvn dependency:list`

Comment: @seenukarthi   I see only one version=2.9.8 in dependency:list. 
But why is dependency:tree's output misleading?